# how to show the bootstrap dynamic tabs in one row without floating down with scroll button to view the tabs

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display the bootstrap tabs dynamical when we click the link it will display the content in tab with close button.

my requirment is to show the tabs in one row without floating down when they are not fit.[image]

Comment: Wrap the tabs with a div what has `white-space: nowrap` property.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are okay with scrollbars in case of overflow, then a simple `white-space: nowrap` would do.

However scrollbar would appear below. You might consider something a bit more UI friendly like using the material design tabs component. Example here: http://codepen.io/thomaskokholm/pen/LWOPRg